# change a list into a dictionary with random values

Tags: python

How do we change a list into a dictionary?

for example we want to make the list `l=["cat","dog","elephant","chicken","lion"]` into `{"cat":0, "dog":1,"elephan":2, "chicken":3, "lion":4}`
 I think I can get a dictionary with all values equals to 0 by `dict.fromkeys(l, 0)`. But I need a dictionary with distinct values

Comment: Use a dictionary comprehension with enumerate. Assuming all the elements in your list are unique: `{key: n for n, key in enumerate(my_list)}`. Or using the integers as the keys (in which case you can have duplicate elements in your list): `{n: val for n, val in enumerate(my_list)}`

Answer (score 1):

If the intention is to get the frequency of the words, you can use Counter from collections. The fromkeys method of dict doesn't accept callable as value for it's second argument, you can use dict comprehension without any limits otherwise!

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> l=["cat","dog","elephant","chicken","lion"]
>>> d=Counter(l)
>>> d
Counter({'cat': 1, 'dog': 1, 'elephant': 1, 'chicken': 1, 'lion': 1})
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try the below code:

```py
import random

l=["cat","dog","elephant","chicken","lion"] # keys
value = random.sample(range(1, 100), len(l)) # values

my_dict = list(zip(l,value))
my_dict = dict(my_dict)

print(my_dict)
```